# Failed to load the package list (trying to install flash player) (Lubuntu 13.04)

Tags: apt, software-center, lubuntu, flash, software-sources

I'm trying to find a solution for a few days, I hope someone can answer me.
I tried several times to install flash player through lubuntu software center, and after I hit "Install Packages" it gives me an error:

```
 Failed to load the package list
This is a serious problem. Try again later. If this problem appears again, please report an error to the developers. >Details E:Type 'sudo' is not known on line 60 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list .
```

I think that I accidently, couple weeks ago, tried to add reposetories to my sources.list and I saved it. If this the problem, is there a way to make a new sources.list?

Comment: Does your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file contain a line starting with `sudo`? This file should normally contain only lines starting  with `deb` or `deb-src` and comments starting with `#`.

Answer (score 0):

The line 60 of your sources.list has something that it shouldn't have. You can fix the line using `sed`:

```
sudo sed -e '60d' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

The `-e` edit the file in place, the `60` indicates the line, `d` indicates that stop right there.